# trying to add another layout horizontal to my layout vertical but get error message

Tags: android-studio, layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pCXh.png)

I tried to create another layout horizontal inside a layout vertical but android studios say my layout horizontal has no parent and has no use, even after I nested in my layout vertical(the parent). I'm trying to create another row for my calculator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just using the TextView for example, but I use this all the time and it works without issue.

Make sure you've declared xml namespace in your parent layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```